# data is not updating to database when i click save

Tags: java, jdbc

my problem is with updating data to database. i had a table with four buttons save,edit,delete,cancel when i click edit the values from database will come to my table then i will edit the values and click the save button then it should get updated.  but it is not getting updated so plz help me

```
try
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    System.out.println("driver loaded");
    System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
    Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms?user=root&password=root");
    System.out.println("Connection created");
    PreparedStatement ps =null;
    if(saveOrUpdate.equals("update"))
    {
        ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("update recipts set  R_RegNo_i=?, R_PatientId_v=?, R_BillAmt_f=?, R_Amount_f=?, R_BilledBy_v =?, R_PaymentMode_v=?, R_ChequeNo_v=?, R_ChequeDate_d=?, R_BankName_v=?, R_CCName_v=?, R_CCHolder_v=?, R_CCType_v=? where R_RecNo_i=? , R_RecDate_d=? , R_BillDate_d=? and R_PatBillNo_v=?");

        ps.setString(1,regNo);
        ps.setString(2,patId);
        ps.setString(3,billAmt);
        ps.setString(4,amt);
        ps.setString(5,billBy);
        ps.setString(6,payMode);
        ps.setString(7,cheNo);
        ps.setString(8,cheDate);
        ps.setString(9,bankName);
        ps.setString(10,ccName);
        ps.setString(11,ccHold);
        ps.setString(12,ccType);
        ps.setString(13,recNo);
        ps.setString(14,recDate);
        ps.setString(15,billDate);
        ps.setString(16,pbillNo);

        a1=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(a1==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Inserted");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "updatesuccess");
        }

    }
    else
    {

        ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("insert into recipts(R_RecNo_i ,R_RecDate_d ,R_BillDate_d ,R_PatBillNo_v ,R_RegNo_i ,R_PatientId_v,R_BillAmt_f  ,R_Amount_f  ,R_BilledBy_v  ,R_PaymentMode_v  ,R_ChequeNo_v  ,R_ChequeDate_d  ,R_BankName_v ,R_CCName_v ,R_CCHolder_v ,R_CCType_v) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1,recNo);
        ps.setString(2,recDate);
        ps.setString(3,billDate);
        ps.setString(4,pbillNo);
        ps.setString(5,regNo);
        ps.setString(6,patId);
        ps.setString(7,billAmt);
        ps.setString(8,amt);
        ps.setString(9,billBy);
        ps.setString(10,payMode);
        ps.setString(11,cheNo);
        ps.setString(12,cheDate);
        ps.setString(13,bankName);
        ps.setString(14,ccName);
        ps.setString(15,ccHold);
        ps.setString(16,ccType);

        a1=ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Inserted");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "success");
    }
}
catch(Exception e1)
{
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    request.getSession().setAttribute("status1", "fail");
}

response.sendRedirect("receipts.jsp");
```

Comment: That `and` at the end of your `UPDATE` seems wrong, it should be a `,`.

Comment: @ashot i tried its not working

Comment: It should be a `,` or `WHERE` (depends on your needs) instead of `AND`. Does it generates an exception?

Comment: Why are you continuously casting to `Connection` (which I assume is a class other than `java.sql.Connection`)? You should use `java.sql.Connection` and then you won't need to cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
update recipts 
    set  R_RegNo_i=?, R_PatientId_v=?, R_BillAmt_f=?, R_Amount_f=?, R_BilledBy_v =?, R_PaymentMode_v=?, R_ChequeNo_v=?, R_ChequeDate_d=?, R_BankName_v=?, R_CCName_v=?, R_CCHolder_v=?, R_CCType_v=? 
    where R_RecNo_i=? AND 
        R_RecDate_d=? AND 
        R_BillDate_d=? AND 
        R_PatBillNo_v=?
```

Comment: @rafal thank u i had a small doubt, when i am editing those four fields they not geting edited y? can u explain plz

Comment: @saideep because in multiple `WHERE` clause, you need to use `AND` or `OR`

Comment: you should try it. if you use `OR`, that means it will edited when at least **one** of the `WHERE` clause is true. if you use `AND`, it will edited only when **all** of the `WHERE` clauses is true

Comment: @rafal its not working with OR and those four fields are primary keys

Comment: if they are primary keys, then of course you can't update it using `OR`. Simple analogy, _"you have a lock with 4 digits security codes, you can't unlock it if you only know one of the digits"_

Comment: You can use `AND` and only update fields which is not primary key. In your above statement, you included primary key `set  R_RegNo_i=?, ...` which make it failed to update

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change your `prepareStatement` from this:

```
... R_BillDate_d=? and R_PatBillNo_v=?");
```

to something like this:

```
... R_BillDate_d=?, R_PatBillNo_v=?");
```